# How can I list unexported functions of a package?

Tags: r, function

I need a list of all functions of a package including the unexported ones, I had no luck with `ls` :

```
"aggregate.data.frame" %in% ls("package:stats",all.names=TRUE) # TRUE
"aggregate.formula" %in% ls("package:stats",all.names=TRUE)    # FALSE
typeof(stats:::aggregate.formula) # [1] "closure"
```

How can I get a list containing `'aggregate.formula'` ?

Comment: As @李哲源 mentioned try `grep("aggregate", ls(getNamespace("stats"), all.names = TRUE), value = TRUE)`

Comment: perfect thanks! so the key is to use `getNamespace("stats")` in `ls` and not the `"package:stats"` notation. I'll accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `getNamespace` in `ls` to return all the unexported functions

```
"aggregate.formula" %in% ls(getNamespace("stats"), all.names = TRUE)
#[1] TRUE
```